# TIZEN List of Privileges

Tags: javascript, security, web-applications, tizen, tizen-web-app

I've looked far and wide and I am not able to find a full list of TIZEN privileges. I need to review privileges for all levels, including "partner" and above, as well as review legacy privileges, which are no longer accepted for the latest TIZEN versions.

Is anyone aware of such a list existing? The documentation available to me does not provide the answer and I have seen such a list a while back, but cannot find it anymore.

Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with this list? It has partner privilegues as well. https://www.tizen.org/privilege

Comment: The fact it's missing all SAMSUNG API privileges. For example: http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/adstreamingfw

Comment: The reason I am looking specifically is a privelege I found that contains the word "logger". However apart from the fact it exists I have no info on this privilege. The privilege was found on the SAMSUNG B2B forums, in one of the guides. I would like to know what it's for.

Comment: found some more here https://github.com/blimJS/Samsung-development-guide/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes, this is better. However it's still not a complete list. The privilege I am looking for is not on that list: http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/logging Found on: http://www.samsungdforum.com/B2B/Guide/BriefGuide/SSSP4#2.4.-Using-Emulator

Comment: I will also note, that it's somewhat irritating to see this question downvoted, given I did prior research and so far nobody has been able to provide an adequate answer.

Comment: There are some people who actually doesn't know the answer, but show their power of down-voting. Its really frustrating for new users...